# Accessing the Profile object from Code Behind Bug? (ASP.NET 2.0 Provider Model)

Tags: asp.net, profile, provider

I have been playing around w/ ASP.NET's Membership, Roles, and Profile providers.  In doing so, I recently set up Microsoft Sample's custom Table Profile Provider (see: http://www.asp.net/downloads/sandbox/table-profile-provider-samples/)

When I run the test solution I have programatic access to the Profile variables.  I.e. I can type Profile. in the code behind and Intellsense will give me access to my custom Profile variables (setup in the web.config) ... LastName, FirstName, Age, etc.

However, when I set up the same scenario in my own solution and type in Profile. in code-behind, it does not recognize the object in IntelliSense and won't compile if I type it myself.

That being said... If I type <%= Profile. in the front end, VS gives me what I'm looking for (the front end Intellisense pops up with my defined Profile variables)

Has anyone else had this problem / Know a solution

Thanks!

-Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems my issue is that Profile is only valid for the VS.NET Website Template (NOT for the Web Application Template)

-Mike

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Is there a way to convert to VS website template? Why isn't web app supported? Don't most people use that template?

Comment: @Zaff, you have to use Project Type "Website", NOT "Web Application"

Answer (score 2):

For Web Application projects, see here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WebProfileBuilder