# Asp.net Membership Profile FirstName and LastName (Not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level )

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, asp.net-membership, profile-provider, sqlprofileprovider

When i created a profile and when i add items it always says not declared in the code behind!!

I tried to change the Framework of the project from Framework 4.0 to Framework 3.5 and it still didn't work.

It says FirstNamep , LastNamep are not declared .

And in the **Web.config** :

```
   <profile defaultProvider="CustomProfileProvider" enabled="true">

   <providers>

  </providers>

  <!-- Define the properties for Profile... -->
  <properties>
      <add name="FirstNamep" type="String" />
      <add name="LastNamep" type="String" />

  </properties>
</profile>
```

**Behind the Code:**

```
    Profile.FirstNamep = FirstNameTextBox.Text 
    Profile.LastNamep = LastNameTextBox.Text
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing the Profile object from Code Behind Bug? (ASP.NET 2.0 Provider Model)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407845/accessing-the-profile-object-from-code-behind-bug-asp-net-2-0-provider-model)

Comment: Is it a website or WAP template you're using? Profiles are not available out of the box with the latter.

Answer (score 0):

The properties are dynamically generated at runtime, which means you can't access them from code-behind.  What you can do is access them from your .ASPX pages using a script block (if that works for you).  Like this.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">
    public void Page_Init()
    {
        Profile.FirstNamep = "some dood";
    }
</script>

<div>Your name is <%= Profile.FirstNamep %></div>
```

It seems to be sort of "by design" that the Profile is available to .aspx pages, but not to the code behind.

---

If you've defined the default provider as **CustomProfileProvider**, then that [has to be a class that inherits `System.Web.Profile.ProfileProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0580x1f5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  Otherwise, you should [use the default SQL profile provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/014bec1k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>

<membership>
    <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
```

Comment: @FBEvo1 you defined it as "CustomProfileProvider"... that has to be a real time, otherwise use the SQL profile provider: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/014bec1k(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: thank you i changes it from CustomProfileProvider to AspNetSqlProfileProvider and its running , However if i want to create a FirstName and LastName entry in my Register page so each User can have a FirstName and LastName  and when they login instead of the UserName being displayed i want (FirstName + LastName), how can i do that?

Comment: @FBEvo1 can't you just write `<%= Profile.FirstName + " " + Profile.LastName %>` wherever you want it displayed?

Comment: ok thanks again, Currently i have A FirstName and LastName textBox in my User Registration Page,so when i click the finish signup button how can it save  the first and last name entries? ,Btw you have been very Helpful!

Comment: @FBEvo1 in the page load event (in the script block), just check for `Page.IsPostback`, then set the values using `Profile.FirstNamep = FirstName.Text`, and then `Profile.Save()`.